# falcon, AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'create'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, falconframework

I'm trying test my falcon routes, but tests always failed, and looks like I make all things right.

my `app.py`

```
import falcon
from resources.static import StaticResource


api = falcon.API()
api.add_route('/', StaticResource())
```

and my test directory `tests/static.py`

```
from falcon import testing
import pytest
from app import api


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client():
    # Assume the hypothetical `myapp` package has a
    # function called `create()` to initialize and
    # return a `falcon.API` instance.
    return testing.TestClient(api.create())


def test_get_message(client):
    result = client.simulate_get('/')
    assert result.status_code == 200
```

Help please, why I got `AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'create'`
 error? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the *hypothetical* `create()` function in your `app.py`.

Your `app.py` should look like the following:

```
import falcon
from resources.static import StaticResource

def create():
    api = falcon.API()
    api.add_route('/', StaticResource()) 
    return api

api = create()
```

Then in your `tests/static.py` should look like:

```
from falcon import testing
import pytest
from app import create


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client():
    return testing.TestClient(create())

def test_get_message(client):
    result = client.simulate_get('/')
    assert result.status_code == 200
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for hint! but I just put api instance into create function, and everything is good, also edited your answer.