# How to perform unit test for Falcon API python

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest, falconframework

I have developed an application using [Falcon framework](https://falconframework.org/) in Python language. I developed few API, Now I wanted to perform unit test so I used unittest package,  But I am not able to test my APIs as it fails unittest.
For testing I refer this [doc](http://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/testing.html) 
I tried to simulate the get method but it asking me argument. Also I am unable to perform any put or post testing.
Here are my code to perform unit test

main.py

```
from app.api.v1 import scheduler
self.add_route('/v1/schedulers', scheduler.SchedulerCollection())
```

scheduler.py

class SchedulerCollection(BaseResource):

```
def __init__(self):
    db = redis_db.RedisStorageEngine()
    self.r = db.connection()

"""
Handle for endpoint: /v1/schedulers
"""
```

# @falcon.before(validate_scheduler_create)
    def on_post(self, req, res):

```
    #some code here

#@falcon.before(auth_required)
def on_get(self, req, res):

    #some code here
```

scheduler_test.py

```
import sys, os
import unittest
import json
from falcon import testing
from app.api.v1 import scheduler

class SchedulerTestCase(testing.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(SchedulerTestCase, self).setUp()
        self.app = scheduler.SchedulerCollection.on_get 

class TestMyApp(SchedulerTestCase):
    def test_get_schedulers(self):
        doc = {u'message': u'Hello world!'}
        result = self.simulate_get('/v1/schedulers')
        result = self.simulate_get('/v1/schedulers')
        self.assertEqual(result.json, doc)




if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

After running test I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/scheduler_test.py", line 17, in setUp
    self.app = scheduler.SchedulerCollection().on_get(self.api_class)
TypeError: on_get() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First off, `self.app` should be initialize with your falcon app, not the method you are testing. Secondly, `simulate_get` is an attribute of `self.app` (not self).

Check more info at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274942/falcon-attributeerror-api-object-has-no-attribute-create/43278734#43278734).